# Is there a need to plug a Powerline Networking plug directly into the wall socket?

Tags: powerline-networking

I read that I will have to plug my Powerline Networking plug directly into the wall socket, but it appears it works fine when I plug it into one of those [extension cords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_cord)

I wonder whats the rational behind the need to plug directly into the wall socket? Does it work lousier when I plug into an extension? Isn't the wall sockets something like an extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two reasons why you should plug direct into the wall:

1:  The more devices you have plugged in between you and the wall, the more chance you have of interference in the signal.

2: Some extension sockets contain filters and surge protectors.  These interfere with the signal.

Yes, it will work fine in a non-surge protected extension, but you may not get quite such a clean signal, and hence not quite as much speed, as if it were plugged direct into the wall.

Comment: will it also still work even if it's connected to an electric splitter ? even if one of the sockets is connected to a computer?

Answer (score 0):

Longer wire = more noise.  Unshielded wire = more noise.  Running through power conditioning or a transformer = ruinous noise.  It's not obvious from the outside of a power strip what circuits it has inside.  A power strip may be simple and cause little problems.  An uninterruptible power supply would probably ruin the data signal.

Comment: Electrical wiring is unshielded and the length of an interior extension cord is typically insignificant compared to the wiring runs, so it isn't clear why those would be significant.  In-cord power conditioning (filters/surge protectors) were already covered in the accepted answer.  UPS isn't what the question is about.

Answer (score -1):

My power extender TPlink AV500 works perfectly well via an extension cord with no obvious drop in speed that I have noticed.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please avoid asking a question in an answer. Instead, ask your own question, and edit out the "question" from this answer.